# Torch/Flashlight won't turn on with Android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am practicing building Android apps and figured starting with a flashlight would be a great beginner step. After having my code blow up several times, I have the app stable where it no longer force closes.

However, the LED camera flash doesn't turn on like I was hoping it should.

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be most helpful.

```
public class PMATorch extends Activity {

private Camera camera;
private Button button;
private Camera.Parameters param;
private boolean torchStat = false;
public Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;
}

private void torchOn(){
    if (camera != null){
        Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        camera.startPreview();
        torchStat = true;
    }
}
private void torchOff(){
    if (camera != null){
        Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        camera.stopPreview();
        torchStat = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pmatorch);
    camera = getCameraInstance();
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.torchOnOff);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (torchStat = false) {
                torchOn();

            } else {
                torchOff();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Edit: I have the permissions and features set in AndroidManifest.xml.

Edit 2: Updated the code to what I just tried running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Camera camera;
```

is never assigned anything. So `if (camera != null){` in `torchOn` won't do anything. You probably wanted to do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    camera = getCameraInstance(); // <<
```

---

```
public Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;
}
```

has furthermore 2 minor problems:
* `catch (Exception e) {}` hides anything that might go wrong here. I would add at least a logging statement like `Log.e("PMATorch", "getCameraInstance", e)`.
* Cosmetical issue: `camera.open()` screams `NullPointerException` at first glance. Change to `Camera.open()` - the method is static and belongs to the class.

E.g. (IMO nicer to read if you get rid of the local variable so I removed that as well)

```
public Camera getCameraInstance() {
    try {
        return Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("PMATorch", "getCameraInstance", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

To further help with debugging such a problem. Add Log to the place that actually causes the action that doesn't seem to work.

```
private void torchOn(){
    if (camera != null){
        Log.d("PMATorch", "now actually turning on");
        ...
```

You will find that In many cases code you think is not working is actually not executed. When that happen, trace back the path that leads there, either with more log or by using the debugger and stepping though the code.

Comment: I did not notice that one. :( This is probably the correct answer for the OP but I think my answer also provides some information so I will keep it there unless it is proven wrong.

Comment: @Keale probably, I have actually no idea how to use camera correctly :D

Comment: Well yeah, if you analyze his code you will see that `getCameraInstance()` is never called so the camera will always be null. Then in his torchOn() method a null check for the camera is present, so if the camera is null, his null check will work so the light wont turn on. You must be a really experienced programmer to notice that >_<

Comment: Going to try changing if (camera != null) to if (torchStat = false) to see if that works.

Comment: @Novabreaker No you must instantiate the camera variable by assigning it to the getCameraInstance() as shown in this answer. I think that will fix your problem.

Comment: Added that instantiate, no light still.

Comment: @Keale Uninitialized fields are quite commong. You'll quickly learn to look for such things if you are regularly answering questions on SO. I am on the other hand working full time as android dev and in touch with programming for even longer.

Comment: @Novabreaker how about my solution, have you tried it?

Comment: @zapl I just code Android casually as I am assigned to web development now so I kinda lost my touch. Good find though, in my next answers I'll try to look for uninitialized fields too

Comment: Tried it, still no LED.

Comment: So, apparently I needed to then call the camera onCreate after everything else.

Comment: Did this work? what exactly did you do to fix your problem? Also I noticed that you did `torchStat = false`. In here you used `=`. You should use `==` in comparing variables with primitive types. the `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that = doesn't mean equal. I also realized I was never opening the camera at any point, which means the light won't come on.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON`, try using `Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH` on your torchOn() method.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) on Camera Parameters

> Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON: Flash will always be fired during snapshot.
>   Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH: Constant emission of light during preview, auto-focus and snapshot.

In my understanding using `Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON` will only turn on the light once and instantly or only if a picture is being taken. `Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH` will *constantly* emit light so this option fits your requirement of having a light turned on when a button is pressed.

A nice tutorial on creating a flashlight application can be found [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/).